# Open url in webview React native push notification

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo, ionic-react

I want to develop an app where I can send remote push notifications to react native app. The push notification will contain a url link and when a user clicks on that link, the app should open up that link in the app (webview)

Is this possible with react native or expo?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
What Thea wants to do is possible
You can ask a more specific question and we can help more

Comment: it is possible in react native, have you tried push notification ?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, however, there are a number of variables to consider with this in order to give clear direction on how to accomplish the desired outcome. For example, how are you handling push notifications? Expo Push Notifications is pretty simple solution. How  are you handling users in your app (are they logging in, subscribing to certain push notifications, anonymous, etc.). This is important information to know what the next steps are.

Here is some documentation from Expo on notifications API:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/